# Python Assigning CSV File to a Variable

Tags: python, arrays, csv

My task was to import a CSV File and make it into an array, which I have done. Now my task now is to assign the data to a variable- is this possible? For instance, how would I go about accessing the 2nd column to the array by typing in myVariableName[1] ?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print(np.array(row))
f.close()
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at `np.loadtxt` or `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: Hint, you've already assigned other things to variable names.  e.g. `f = open("Test.csv")` assigns the file object that is returned by `open` to the variable `f`.  You did it again with `csv_f`.  From here, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to assign a variable name to any particular object in the code ...

Comment: I've tried to assign a variable however is it possible to include the "for" statement as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt).

**a.csv:**

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt(open("a.csv","rb"),delimiter=",")
print(matrix[:,1])
# prints [ 2.  5.  8.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to which items from column 2 can be appended as you process each row from the CSV file. The following code will contain items from column 2 in the variable `column_2`:

```
import csv

column_2 = []
f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    column_2.append(row[1])
f.close()
print column_2
```

You could replace all of that code with a list comprehension:

```
import csv

column_idx = 1
with open('Test.csv') as f:
    column_2 = [row[column_idx] for row in csv.reader(f)]
print column_2
```